# Show that $\lim_{t\to 0}H(t)$ does not exist using $\varepsilon$ - $\delta$ definition.

Tags: calculus, epsilon-delta

Let $H(t)$ be the heaviside function

$$H(t) = \begin{cases} 1, \quad &t\ge 0\\ 0, \quad &t<0\end{cases}.$$

Prove that $\lim_{t\to 0}H(t)$ does not exist using $\varepsilon$ - $\delta$ definition.

Hint: let $\varepsilon = \frac 12$ and suppose $\lim_{t\to 0}H(t) = L$

I have in my mind that I should separate this into cases, and those are when $t \lt 0$  or  $t \ge 0$, but I can't formalize it the way the proof requires. My attempt was the following:

Suppose $\lim_{t\to 0}H(t) = L$

$\forall \varepsilon \gt 0$, $\exists  \delta \gt 0$ s.t.

$0 \lt |t| \lt \delta$ $\implies$ $|H(t) - L| \lt \frac 12$

If $t$ aproaches $0$ from the right, we would have $|1 - L| \lt \frac 12$, and $|0 - L| \lt \frac 12$ if it's coming from the left. From here I have no idea.

Comment: Should the limit be $\lim_{t \to 0}$ instead of $\lim_{x\to 0}$?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Just fixed it.

Comment: Are you told what $H(t)$ is?

Comment: It is Heaviside's function.

Comment: What is $H?$  The unit step function?

Comment: Yes, this function.

Comment: If the limit exists then there must be an $L$ such that $|L|<\frac 12$ and $|1-L| < \frac 12$ and no such L exists.

Comment: Could you detail a bit more?

Comment: What does the triangle inequality tell you if $|1-L|<1/2$ and $|0-L|<1/2$?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $\lim_{t \to 0} H(t)=L$. Then by definition, for any $\varepsilon>0$, we can find a $\delta>0$ such that
$$|t-0|<\delta \implies |H(t)-L|<\varepsilon$$
If this is true for any epsilon, let's try $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{2}$.

Case 1: Suppose $t>0$. Then $H(t)=1$. So by assumption, $\exists\delta>0$ such that
$$|t|<\delta \implies |1-L|<\frac{1}{2}$$

Case 2: Suppose $t<0$. Then $H(t)=0$. So by assumption, $\exists\delta>0$ such that
$$|t|<\delta \implies |0-L|<\frac{1}{2}$$

There is no number $L$ such that $|1-L|<\frac{1}{2}$ and $|0-L|<\frac{1}{2}$ are both true. Can you explain why? Therefore, we have reached a contradiction, and our original assumption is false.

Comment: Is it because $|0 - L| = |-L| = |L| \lt \frac 12$? So if I apply triangle inequality in $|1 -L| \lt \frac 12$ it'd tell me that 1 + L is less than $\frac 12$?

Comment: Triangle inequality wasn't my first instinct, but it will work. Why can't $|L|<\frac{1}{2}$ and $1+L<\frac{1}{2}$ be true simultaneously?

Comment: Because $|L|$ is positive/non-negative, so $1 + L \ge1$.

Comment: Hmm I don't think that logic works here. If I understand your argument correctly, you can claim, 
$$|L|\ge 0 \implies 1+|L|\ge 1$$
which doesn't really accomplish much.
From algebra, how can I rewrite $|L|<a$?

Comment: $-a \lt L \lt a$. What logic would you use?

Comment: Perfect. Then the first statement says $-\frac{1}{2} < L < \frac{1}{2}$ and the second says $1+ L <\frac{1}{2} \iff L < -\frac{1}{2}$. There is clearly no $L$ that satisfies both.

Comment: Oh! Got it! Thank you for help!